# Extract packet payload from pcap file

Tags: udp, pcap, tshark

For a project I am working on we have a data source which generates a stream of data as UDP packets on 100 GbE Ethernet link.

The engineers I am working with can capture this stream and write the full stream as a pcap file.

I would like to strip ***all*** network headers and create a new file with just the UDP datagramme payload. I realise I can write some C or python to do this using the Pcap libraries, but I would prefer to use an existing tool such as tshark. Particularly if this gives the option of (optional) packet filtering such as UDP port etc.

I have been looking for solutions with google and reading man page but could not find any solution.

I do *NOT* want the data converted to hex - I want the binary data of the payload retained.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this command?

This command looks for incoming UDP packets, extracts the UDP payload from them, sends them to the `xxd` command for hex to raw byte conversion and saves the raw bytes into a file as they come in.

```
tshark -i eno1 -Y 'udp.port == 67 or udp.port == 58' -T fields -e udp.payload | xxd -r -p > raw_payloads.bin
```

`-i` Specifies what interface you want to capture packets from.
`-Y` Specifies how to filter packets. In my example, filter out packets where the UDP port equals 67 or 68. List of filters can be found here: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/
`-T` Specifies where we are going to look (e.i. fields), in our case we want to look into the `udp.payload` field
`-e` Specifies the field to read (e.i. `udp.payload` field)

This will output all the UDP payloads into hex.

We can convert the hex into raw bytes by piping the output into `xxd`.
`-r` will convert hex to binary
`-p` will output the binary continuously

Then finally we save the raw bytes into a file: `> raw_payloads.bin`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks - I had actually come up with a similar solution, but ideally would prefer to not have to do the ascii to binary step (ie tshark directly dump binary). I have large captures to process.